# Resetting an HTML page with full AJAX

Tags: jquery, html

I have setup a online bank system using full ajax. This means that everything happens on one page.

```
<div class="login">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="password" class="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="nickname"></div>
    <div class="balance"></div>
    <div class="transactions"></div>
</div>
```

The dividers `login` and `dashboard` are initially hidden on page load, but, based on the existence and  the validity of sessions, are shown. (So if you are logged in, dashboard shows, and if you're not, login shows)

In the dashboard, there is sensitive data such as your current balance, your recent transactions and more. When a user decides to log out, that information is still present within the HTML.

I do not want to do something such as:

```
$(".nickname").html('');
$(".balance").html('');
$(".transactions").html('');
```

Note that I have much more markup, nested, and more complex than just `.html`.

**I do not wish to just refresh the page on log out.**

By not refreshing the page, I can not delete HTML nodes such as `$(".dashboard").html()`, as that would break any code that puts data into those divs after a person logs in.

What I'm trying to prevent is say, someone who logs in, logs out, then someone else comes in, and uses firebug/chrome dev console to peak at the source dashboard. Currently what happens is, the dashboard is hidden, cookie is removed, and login is shown. The data in the dashboard is not cleared.

Is there a way I could save the current HTML page, then when the user logs out, I can reset the entire page without refreshing?

Comment: don't put `dashboard` even hidden while not logged in...

Comment: If it's non-existent, then when someone logs in, elements within dashboard will not load. On page load, `dashboard`'s contents are just a template for soon to be sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the dashboard:

```
$('.dashboard-template').clone().addClass('dashboard').insertBefore('.dashboard-template');
```

Then fill in the relevant information, and remove it when logged out.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up having a main display `view`, and having whatever component I required cloned from templates (which were always hidden). +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to writing similar systems is to have the login page separate. Once logged in, everything is built by AJAX. On logout, the user is sent back to the login page. The use of a one-use security code to build the page stops returning to the browler's previous page.

That said, I'm not sure how you can avoid using something like `html('')` or why such a solution is so undesirable. Perhaps `.remove()` - see [here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)?

Comment: Thanks! I considered this, but then it wouldn't be full ajax. The one and only page is `index.html`, there is no serverside involvement (only in XHR). I can use `.html('')` to clear, but it would be difficult because there are too many elements to consider. I would like it to be reset back to the original.

Comment: @DaveChen Could you remove() the dashboard and html() the login back to default? You could create the dashboard element from scratch for each login.

Answer (score 0):

you can stock data in cache using webstorage, save data when user log in, catch data, fill your form then delete data in web storage